# how can I append 2 dataframes in pyspark and keep both headers in first and second rows? or add the 2nd header to a dataframe with already 1 header?

Tags: csv, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, header

I'm trying to write a sparksql code (pyspark) in databricks which append 2 dataframes in a CSV file, but there is an issue that I need to keep both headers of these 2 dataframes because I gonna use these two headers as metadata in next step. Could you please help me how could I do that, two first rows should read as headers.

```
%python
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df12= spark.read.csv ("/FileStore/tables/BBrate.csv")
df12.write.csv(path="/opt/Output/test5.csv", mode="append")
df12= df12.select (col("_c0").alias("IntCurrates"), col("_c1").alias(" "), 
col("_c2").alias(" "),col("_c3").alias(" "), col("_c4").alias(" "), 
col("_c5").alias(" "))
df12.createOrReplaceTempView("BBXrate")
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM BBXrate")
sqlDF.show()
```

To be honest I'm completely beginner in Spark and frankly, what I need to have, are 2 dataframes and append both of them in a CSV file something like the bellow (the second table is just one row as the header) but I know that the below code is not correct. and another point is that mode="append" doesn't work anymore.

```
%python
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df8= spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/BBrate.csv") 
df9= spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/ETLy.csv")
df8.coalesce(1). write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') 
.save("/FileStore/tables/ETLyardi2.csv").mode("append")
df9.coalesce(1). Write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
.save("/FileStore/tables/ETLy.csv", mode= 'append')
df9.createOrReplaceTempView("BBXrate")
sqlDF9 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM BBXrate")
sqlDF9.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide your code and explain what you are trying to achieve? Thanks

Comment: Also provide dataframe sample schemas for both dframes

Comment: Thank you for your considerations guys, I did update my issue by the codes and uploaded my tables in the linke.: https://file.io/q2KkhX